# mysql seems to be running, yet there is no /var/run/mysqld/mysql.socket

Tags: mysql, akonadi

When running `ps -A | grep mysql` I get the following results:

```
     4046 ?        00:02:27 mysqld
     6489 ?        00:00:00 mysqld
     8399 pts/7    00:00:00 mysql-server-5.
```

When looking into the `/var/run/mysqld` directory there are NO files, not even `mysql.socket`.

When attempting to visit `localhost/ampache/` ampache reports:

`5) { $refresh_limit = Config::get('refresh_limit'); $ajax_url = '?page=index&action=reloadnp'; require_once Config::get('prefix') . '/templates/javascript_refresh.inc.php'; } require_once Config::get('prefix') . '/templates/show_index.inc.php'; UI::show_footer(); ?>`

When visiting `localhost/ampache/install.php` I get the following:

`$web_path, 'database_name' => $database, 'database_username' => $username, 'database_password' => $password, 'database_hostname' => $hostname, 'database_port' => $port ), true); // Charset and gettext setup $htmllang = $_REQUEST['htmllang']; $charset = $_REQUEST['charset']; if (!$htmllang) { if ($_ENV['LANG']) { $lang = $_ENV['LANG']; } else { $lang = 'en_US'; } if(strpos($lang, '.')) { $langtmp = explode('.', $lang); $htmllang = $langtmp[0]; $charset = $langtmp[1]; } else { $htmllang = $lang; } } Config::set('lang', $htmllang, true); Config::set('site_charset', $charset ?: 'UTF-8', true); load_gettext(); header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . Config::get('site_charset')); // Correct potential \ or / in the dirname $safe_dirname = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/\\"); $web_path = $http_type . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $safe_dirname; unset($safe_dirname); switch ($_REQUEST['action']) { case 'create_db': if ($_POST['db_user'] == 'create_db_user') { $new_user = scrub_in($_POST['db_username']); $new_pass = $_POST['db_password']; } if (!strlen($new_user) || !strlen($new_pass)) { Error::add('general', T_('Error: Ampache SQL Username or Password missing')); require_once 'templates/show_install.inc.php'; break; } if (!install_insert_db($new_user, $new_pass, $_POST['overwrite_db'])) { require_once 'templates/show_install.inc.php'; break; } // Now that it's inserted save the lang preference Preference::update('lang', '-1', Config::get('lang')); header ('Location: ' . $web_path . "/install.php?action=show_create_config&local_db=$database&local_host=$hostname&local_port=$port&htmllang=$htmllang&charset=$charset"); break; case 'create_config': $download = (!isset($_POST['write'])); $created_config = install_create_config($download); require_once 'templates/show_install_config.inc.php'; break; case 'show_create_config': require_once 'templates/show_install_config.inc.php'; break; case 'create_account': $results = parse_ini_file($configfile); Config::set_by_array($results, true); $password2 = scrub_in($_REQUEST['local_pass2']); if (!install_create_account($username, $password, $password2)) { require_once Config::get('prefix') . '/templates/show_install_account.inc.php'; break; } header ("Location: " . $web_path . '/login.php'); break; case 'show_create_account': $results = parse_ini_file($configfile); /* Make sure we've got a valid config file */ if (!check_config_values($results)) { Error::add('general', T_('Error: Config file not found or unreadable')); require_once Config::get('prefix') . '/templates/show_install_config.inc.php'; break; } require_once Config::get('prefix') . '/templates/show_install_account.inc.php'; break; case 'init': require_once 'templates/show_install.inc.php'; break; default: // Show the language options first require_once 'templates/show_install_lang.inc.php'; break; } // end action switch ?>`

Previously I tried setting up 'mpd' and 'fookebox' and 'fookebox' fails because there is no `mysql.socket` in the `/var/run/mysqld directory`.

when trying to run `sudo mysql_upgrade` I get the following:

```
    Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
    Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
    Error: Failed while fetching Server version! Could be due to unauthorized access.
    FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

When running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` I can not change the configuration. I have tried reinstalling mysql, and have also found something else weird.

Each time I restart my system akonadi creates a new directory in /tmp each with the following:

`akonadi-user.??????`

The word "user" in the above is substituted for my username and the ?????? is a random set of characters. When the system shuts-down or starts-up, akonadi must be deleting the directory `akonadi-user.??????` and creating a new one with a different name as there are no other like named directories.

Inside the `akonadi-user.??????` directory I find the following files:

```
    akonadiserver.socket
    mysql.socket
```

Suggestion made to others that I have found on various websites about finding the `msql.socket` in locations than `/var/run/mysqld` was to change the location in the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` configuration file. That however is not possible if the directory is changed with each restart.

What is going on here and how do I get mysql working with ampache and other applications I have been trying use that require mysql? I started to remove akonadi hoping to see if akonadi is to blame, but doing that showed that the addition changed would require removal of KDE and many KDE based apps. KDE "IS" my desktop/gui and can't do without it.

```
H   H EEEEE L     PPPP  !
H   H E     L     P   P !
H   H E     L     P   P !
HHHHH EEEEE L     PPPP  !
H   H E     L     P     !
H   H E     L     P     !
H   H EEEEE LLLLL P     !
```

P.S. I have never been able to add wine to the system, initially needed to setup my system to startup under Upstart instead of systemd. After numerous upgrade it may still be running Upstart in have more recently added systemd hoping to correct the mysql problems. this is a dual-boot with win7 though I almost NEVER run winblows.

Comment: It is generally best to ask just one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem:

`mysql-problem: [ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock`

I solved it with this commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

If you already have /var/run/mysql, change the owner to mysql.

Comment: The system changes it to root on reboot

Comment: sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld    changes ownership, but on reboot the system changes it back to root. I tried changing permissions (chmod) still no mysql.socket

Comment: the owner is changed back to root? this is strange!

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, when I said it change ownership, I meant it partially changes ownership... chown

Comment: I meant it changes group ownership.  Using "chown mysql:mysql mysqld". It changes ownership of owner and group to "/var/run/mysqld". On reboot the file "/var/run/mysqld/mysql.socket" still does not exist. I recheck the ownership of "/var/run/mysql" and the owner is mysql and the group is root. I previously set the permissions of the directory to 'rwxrwxrwx' so mysql could write to "/var/run/mysql" regardless and still have no mysql.socket. There is a file /tmp/akonadi-user.??????/mysql.socket but the directory changes at each reboot and other software doesn't know where that file is located.

Comment: look into /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: It is empty, as is /var/log/mysql/error.log.1

Comment: There are three file in that directory file:///var/log/mysql/error.log
file:///var/log/mysql/error.log.1
file:///var/log/mysql/error.log.3.gz
file:///var/log/mysql/error.log.4.gz
file:///var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index

Comment: the two .gz file are 20bytes all others 0 bytes. Meaning all are basically empty files.

Comment: when I run "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start" I get the following:
"start: Job is already running: mysql"

Comment: mysql IS running based on the above "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start" command as well as using the "ps -A | grep mysql" command to see if a myqsl process is running. Yet I cannot seem to access mysql.

Comment: I would suggest to uninstall mysql and install it again. If you have your databases in your personal home directory, this should be no problem.

Comment: Reinstalled after Total removal same issue.

Comment: you are on ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: kubuntu 14.04..

Comment: I have tried using installing kubuntu/ubuntu 16.xx and cannot install it. It never completes the install. In fact, it gets most the way to installing, it reboots as if to start running on the "instaled OS" but it fails to boot up. Had this problem on more than one computer, no matter how many copies of 16.xx I download. Mayve because I am installing from USC thumb drive, IDK.